# how to select static dropdown using selenium if select tag is not available

Tags: python, selenium

the select method can be only used for static dropdown only if there is a select tag but how to select in the static dropdown if the tag is p-dropdown not select is there an alternative to it ?

Comment: Just .click() on the element that handles the click event. It should open up the elements than procede to .click() on them as well.

Answer (score 0):

select class in selenium is just a helper method for selecting from a dropdown, it works only with select tag.  For other tags use :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpathofdropdown").click()
WebDriverWait(browser, 15).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
    (By.XPATH, 'xpathofanyoption'))).click()
```

Here we are clicking the drop down and clicking the option when its visible , we use expected condition to wait for visibility